# Use same AccountType to store credentials in the AccountManager across several apps with different signing certificate

Tags: android, accountmanager, securityexception

We are developing a library which handles authentication for several apps with different signing certificates. This library, exposes several methods to call our server (create users, delete them, update data, etc).

The library also takes care of interacting with the AccountManager to store the credentials, which are username, authtoken and refresh token. When a request is made, it's listening for a "401 Unauthorized - token expired" and, in that case, invalidating the token and getting a new one from the AccountManager (which has obtained a new one from our server by using the stored refresh token).

AccountManager has the following feature. When several account share the same account type, the first installed app's AccountAuthenticator (the class which holds all the logic for the AccountAuthenticator) class is used.

To put some names on it, we got AppA and AuthA (AccountAuthenticator class) signed with certificateA and AppB with AuthB signed with certificateB. Both use accountType "sharedname"
AppA is first installed so AuthA is associated with account type "sharedname". Then AppB is installed, as there is already an AccountAuthenticator already associated with accountType "sharedname", AuthA will be used when calling AccountManager from AppB.

Since API 22, some methods from the AccountManager throw a SecurityException when being called from an app signed with a different certificate than the used AccountAuthenticator.

Here goes the problem (finally!):
We got a method *createUser* in our library that creates the user in the server and, if success, inserts the new account in the AccountManager. When calling *createUser* from AppB, a call to `AccountManager.get(mContext).addAccountExplicity(...)' is done and it produces a SecurityException as the used authenticator is AuthA.

AddAccount is not an option (as far as I know) because `createUser` is being called from the login activity of the different apps.

¿How can we add an account to the AccountManager from AppB without using an Activity?

We got the same problems to remove the account with AccountManager.get(mContext).removeAccount(...);

I hope it is clear, let me know if you need a better explanation, which is possible.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you find an answer for this eventually? Or did you end up using any another solution?